# Moment.js Real time with timezone

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to store an unix value from a Time input.

The problem is that :

```
// I create a Moment Date from my input :
var date = moment({hour: 10, minute: 00)
// gives this _d : Mon May 04 2015 10:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)

// I convert it to unix value
date = date.unix()
// -> 1430726400

moment( date ).format('HH:mm')
// -> "14:25" // Should give me 10:00
// Online conversion unix time gives me : Mon, 04 May 2015 08:00:00 GMT
```

So how can I keep my 10:00 in memory as unix value using those transformations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of sorted it this way :

```
// I create a Moment Date from my input :
var date = moment({hour: 10, minute: 00)
// gives this _d : Mon May 04 2015 10:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)

// Convert to unix
date = date.toDate();
date = date.getTime();

console.log(moment( date ).format('HH:mm')); // Gives me 10:00
```

I hope it will keep the good time ? In France the time changes twice a year ( go forward 1 hour, go backwards 1 hour)

Answer (score 0):

Per [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/):

```
moment.unix( date ).format('HH:mm')
```